# Is it possible to use a variable in the right hand side of Kotlin's type casting "is" operator?

Tags: kotlin

Is the below intended operation be achieved in any (common) way in Kotlin?

```
val dataClass = String::class
if (anotherObject is dataClass) { ... }
```

I would want to know if it is possible to check for type casting with a variable on the RHS of the `is` operator. Also any other way of doing this?

There is some concept here that I may have not understood and eventually ended up asking this question here. Please do share any info related to this.

Comment: you can use `anotherObject.javaClass.instanceOf(dataClass)`

Comment: Try use anotherObject.javaClass.kotlin.simpleName=="String"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`KClass.isInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/is-instance.html):

> Returns true if value is an instance of this class on a given platform.

```
val dataClass = String::class
val anotherObject: Any = ""
if (dataClass.isInstance(anotherObject)) {
    println("anotherObject is String!")
}
```

Note that unlike `is`, the type of `anotherObject` will not become `String` inside the if statement, because the compiler does not know what class is inside `dataClass`.

Comment: Thanks!
Is this what `is` operator does under the hood apart from smart casting may be?
Is `is` operator an infix operator? Is there any way I can get hold of the underlying code for `is` operator?

Comment: @VarunMuralidharan `is` is not an infix operator. I'm pretty sure `is` is much more powerful than `KClass.isInstance`. For one, the right hand side of `is` can be any runtime available _type_, not just any type representable by a `KClass`. Anyway, exactly how `is` works is specified [here](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#type-checking-expressions) (there's quite a lot of notation there!). If you are looking for the code implementing `is`, it's somewhere in [this repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin).